# writing JSON data to disk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

What is the easiest way to write a JSON data/NSDictionary and read it back again? I know there's NSFileManager, but is there an open source framework library out there that would make this process easier? Does iOS5 NSJSONSerialization class supports writing the data to disk?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yup, `NSJSONSerialization` is the way to go:

```
NSString *fileName = @"myJsonDict.dat"; // probably somewhere in 'Documents'
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"key" : @"value" };

NSOutputStream *os = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:fileName append:NO];

[os open];
[NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:dict toStream:os options:0 error:nil];
[os close];

// reading back in...
NSInputStream *is = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:fileName];

[is open];
NSDictionary *readDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:is options:0 error:nil];
[is close];

NSLog(@"%@", readDict);
```

Comment: It's weird, I use this exact code and the app consume 100% of CPU at the [NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:dict toStream:os options:0 error:nil]; line and the app just hangs there.

Comment: Ok it was missing getting the full file path

Comment: @VanDuTran I'm having the exact same issue, even when using the full file path. Thoughts?

Comment: @elsurudo it's been too long, I don't work on that project anymore, I can't remember, sorry...

Comment: For those interested, I ended up serializing the JSON to NSData, then writing the NSData out using NSFileManager, which worked fine.

Comment: You can't serialise JSON. JSON _is_ serialised. You can serialise arrays or dictionaries to JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you must ensure that the directories in the path exist, otherwise your app will hang and consume 100% of your CPU when using `+ writeJSONObject:toStream:options:error:`. The file itself will be created by the stream.